# Align Text in Combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, visual-c#-express-2010

I want to align my text in combo box so that it will show in the center of combobox tell me how to do this also you can see there is a default border around a combo box when it is in focus how can i remove that border also
Kindly solve my two problems 
Thanks

Comment: You cannot do this in windows form control specially combo box

Comment: Both requirements are possible, Making the TextAlign Center for edit area and for the dropdown. Also getting rid of focus rectangle. I've shared an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58955315/3110834).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This isn't supported for ComboBox. The exact reasons are lost in the fog of time, ComboBox has been around since the early nineties, but surely has something to do with the awkwardness of getting the text in the textbox portion to line up with the text in the dropdown. Custom drawing with `DrawItem` cannot solve it either; that only affects the appearance of the dropdown items.

As a possible workaround, you could perhaps do something outlandish like padding the item strings with spaces so they *look* centered. You'll need `TextRenderer.MeasureText()` to figure out how many spaces to add for each item.

The "border" you are talking about is not a border, it is the focus rectangle. You can't get rid of that either. Windows refuses to let you create a UI that won't show the control with the focus. Users that prefer the keyboard over the mouse care about that. No workaround for that one.

Comment: `DrawItem` affects the appearance of the selected value of the closed `ComboBox` if the `DropDownStyle` is `DropDownList`, i.e. when the `TextBox` is not editable.

Answer (score 33):

This article will help you: http://blog.michaelgillson.org/2010/05/18/left-right-center-where-do-you-align/

The trick is to set the `DrawMode`-Property of the ComboBox to `OwnerDrawFixed` as well as subscribe to its event `DrawItem`.

Your event should contain the following code:

```
// Allow Combo Box to center aligned
private void cbxDesign_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
  // By using Sender, one method could handle multiple ComboBoxes
  ComboBox cbx = sender as ComboBox;
  if (cbx != null)
  {
    // Always draw the background
    e.DrawBackground();

    // Drawing one of the items?
    if (e.Index >= 0)
    {
      // Set the string alignment.  Choices are Center, Near and Far
      StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
      sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
      sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

      // Set the Brush to ComboBox ForeColor to maintain any ComboBox color settings
      // Assumes Brush is solid
      Brush brush = new SolidBrush(cbx.ForeColor);

      // If drawing highlighted selection, change brush
      if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        brush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;

      // Draw the string
      e.Graphics.DrawString(cbx.Items[e.Index].ToString(), cbx.Font, brush, e.Bounds, sf);
    }
  }
}
```

[image: ComboBox-Preview]

To right align the items you can simply replace `StringAlignment.Center` with `StringAlignment.Far`.

Comment: Important note from the article: to also align the selected item, you need to add `this.comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;`

Answer (score 9):

Set `RightToLeft` property to `true`.
It does NOT reverse the sequence of characters. It only right-justifies.

Comment: True, although it moves the drop-down arrow to the left side aswell.

Comment: That's true, but the scrolling bar goes to the left, as for "right to left" handwriting. That's not a good solution.

Answer (score 3):

The post is a bit old but it may be still worth to say:

both requirements are possible for Windows Forms ComboBox:

- **Text align center (text area and the dropdown)**

  - For the text area, find the `Edit` control and set the `ES_CENTER` style for the control.
  - For the dropdown items or the selected item in drop-down mode, to align text to center, just make the control owner-drawn and draw the text at center.
- **Get rid of focus rectangle**

  - Make the control owner-drawn and just don't draw focus rectangle.

**Example**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyComboBox : ComboBox
{
    public MyComboBox()
    {
        DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
    const int GWL_STYLE = -16;
    const int ES_LEFT = 0x0000;
    const int ES_CENTER = 0x0001;
    const int ES_RIGHT = 0x0002;
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
        public int Width { get { return Right - Left; } }
        public int Height { get { return Bottom - Top; } }
    }
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern bool GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hWnd, ref COMBOBOXINFO pcbi);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct COMBOBOXINFO
    {
        public int cbSize;
        public RECT rcItem;
        public RECT rcButton;
        public int stateButton;
        public IntPtr hwndCombo;
        public IntPtr hwndEdit;
        public IntPtr hwndList;
    }
    protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnHandleCreated(e);
        SetupEdit();
    }
    private int buttonWidth = SystemInformation.HorizontalScrollBarArrowWidth;
    private void SetupEdit()
    {
        var info = new COMBOBOXINFO();
        info.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(info);
        GetComboBoxInfo(this.Handle, ref info);
        var style = GetWindowLong(info.hwndEdit, GWL_STYLE);
        style |= 1;
        SetWindowLong(info.hwndEdit, GWL_STYLE, style);
    }
    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
        e.DrawBackground();
        var txt = "";
        if (e.Index >= 0)
            txt = GetItemText(Items[e.Index]);
        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, txt, Font, e.Bounds,
            ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left | TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this by adding space before Display member in your Query

for example :

```
combobox1.DataSource = Query(Select col1 , ('   '+col2) as Col2 from tableName) 
combobox1.DisplayMember = "Col2";
combobox1.ValueMember = "col1";
```