# Space before text in ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I made custom combobox that have an integrated button to add new item and it works good in case when `DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList` but there is a problem when the combobox `DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown` the text of the combobox is cover the button that I made.

Is there away to make space before text in case when the `DropDownStyle` for the combobox is set to `DropDown`?   You can see the problem in image.

[[Image showing the spacing issue on the combobox][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5VZB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5VZB.png)

```
public class ComboBoxButton3 : ComboBox
{
    public ComboBoxButton3()
    {
        myButton = new Button();

        this.DrawMode = System.Windows.Forms.DrawMode.OwnerDrawVariable;
        this.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
    }

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        this.myButton.Size = new Size(23, this.ClientSize.Height);
        this.myButton.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        this.myButton.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
        this.Button.BackgroundImage = global::RibbonMenuControlTest.Properties.Resources.add1;
        this.Button.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
        this.Button.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.Controls.Add(this.myButton);

        base.OnCreateControl();
    }


    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (this != null)
        {
            e.DrawBackground();
            if (e.Index >= 0)
            {
                StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
                sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

                Brush brush = new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor);

                if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                    brush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;

                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Items[e.Index].ToString(), this.Font, brush, e.Bounds, sf);
            }
        }

        base.OnDrawItem(e);
    }

    public Button myButton;
    public Button Button
    {
        get
        {
            return myButton;
        }
        set
        {
            myButton = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a valid question, I don't see why it deserves many downvotes

Answer (score 0):

Generally, if a control is not designed to do a certain function with ease, there is normally a reason for it. 
I would suggest re-considering your design before going forward.

Regardless, if you insist and continue - then these threads should give you the desired result / point you in the right direction (at least with moving the text around).

[Align Text in Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817062/align-text-in-combobox)

http://blog.michaelgillson.org/2010/05/18/left-right-center-where-do-you-align/

Snippet:

[image: Snippet from source]

Comment: Your code is working only when the
DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList