# Drawing list on right side of combobox in C# (winforms)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

If list in combobox control is wider than combobox how can I draw it on right side of combobox? It is always left aligned.
For example - if combobox location is near right side of form, and list in combobox is wider than width of combobox, part of list is not visible to user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Align Text in Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817062/align-text-in-combobox)

Comment: I don't want to align text in list left or right, but whole list to draw on right side of combobox control.

Comment: So have you actually attempted to do it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I tried something in DrawItem event, but I'm not sure how to get reference to combobox list.

Answer (score 2):

After some searching I managed to find solution on another forum. I've adopted it for C# and changed slightly.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

//  Fix Combo dropdown list if (left or right) off screen.

public class ComboExtended : ComboBox 
{

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private extern static bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)] bool bRepaint);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private extern static bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, ref tagRECT lpRect);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct tagRECT
    {
        public int left, top, right, bottom;
    }

    private const int WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX = 308;
    private bool ListMoved = false;
    protected override void OnDropDownClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDropDownClosed(e);
        ListMoved = false;
    }

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        base.WndProc(ref m);
        if (!ListMoved && m.Msg == WM_CTLCOLORLISTBOX)
        {
            tagRECT rc = new tagRECT();
            GetWindowRect(m.LParam, ref rc);
            Form parentForm = this.FindForm();
            int posLeft = rc.right - rc.left > this.Width ? rc.left - ((rc.right - rc.left) - this.Width) : rc.left;
            int posTop = rc.bottom - rc.top > parentForm.Height - rc.top ? (rc.top - (rc.bottom - rc.top)) - this.Height : rc.top;
            MoveWindow(m.LParam, posLeft, posTop, rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, true);
            ListMoved = true;
        }
    }
}
```