# How to make DataGridViewComboBoxColumn selections alignment center?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

I want to align DataGridViewComboBoxColumn selections text center when in editmode(when click dropdown). I found an approach here:[Align Text in Combobox](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21605647/2268680), to align combobox, and tried to add `EditingControlShowing` event to DGV, and add `DrawItem` event like above approach to align combobox, but it didn't work. Here is the code:

```
private void MyDGV_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
    {
        ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (cb != null)
        {
            cb.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(cbxDesign_DrawItem);
        }
    }
}
private void cbxDesign_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    // By using Sender, one method could handle multiple ComboBoxes
    ComboBox cbx = sender as ComboBox;
    if (cbx != null)
    {
        // Always draw the background
        e.DrawBackground();

        // Drawing one of the items?
        if (e.Index >= 0)
        {
            // Set the string alignment.  Choices are Center, Near and Far
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;

            // Set the Brush to ComboBox ForeColor to maintain any ComboBox color settings
            // Assumes Brush is solid
            Brush brush = new SolidBrush(cbx.ForeColor);

            // If drawing highlighted selection, change brush
            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                brush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;

            // Draw the string
            e.Graphics.DrawString(cbx.Items[e.Index].ToString(), cbx.Font, brush, e.Bounds, sf);
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You know that you can use WPF controls in Winforms? WPF controls give much more style, format options

Comment: It seems you've missed a paragraph of the answer: *The trick is to set the DrawMode-Property of the ComboBox to OwnerDrawFixed as well as subscribe to its event DrawItem.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you need to add these properties for the code to work:

```
private void MyDGV_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Control.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl))
    {
        ComboBox cb = e.Control as ComboBox;
        if (cb != null)
        {
            //add these 2
            cb.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
            cb.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            cb.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(cbxDesign_DrawItem);
        }
    }
}
```